# VIM: disallow focusing a window

Tags: vim

In VIM, I want to split a window in two parts where first one is the regular editor, and the second one is just read-only window for some auxiliary information.

The user should not be allowed to access (focus) the read-only window. Can I set that somehow?

`set nomodifiable` is helpful but it is not what I meant - I still can access the window.

**Edit**

- I mean two independent buffers

Comment: Why? Why forbid to focus that split/window? I am unable to imagine a valid use case for this.

Comment: I want a vertical window of width 1, where I would add some markers that correspond to lines in the editor

Comment: Why didn't you ask for that directly? Maybe a new window is not your best option here?

Comment: @innaM: hmm, you are right. I posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836145/vim-how-to-add-custom-markers-before-lines

Answer (score 1):

Usually the *preview window* is used for auxiliary information, e.g. insert-mode completion can show additional information there. You can `:pedit` a scratch buffer, and show your information there.

I don't follow your requirement of not allowing to move into that window. That's not very Vim-like. You can disallow (accidental) editing with `:setlocal nomodifiable`, but why not allow the user to interact with the window?! (Some operations like resizing are way easier or only possible when you're inside the window.)

#### Alternative

If the amount of information is small and only needs to be displayed for a short time, and you're in GVIM, you can also use tooltip popups via `'balloonexpr'`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean two (or more) windows using same buffer? In that case I think that `modifiable` wouldn't be an option because it wouldn't let you change the data from any window.

You could try to use the `WimEnter` autocommand to come back to the previous window.

```
autocmd WinEnter * exe "normal \<c-w>\<c-p>"
```

Comment: I meant two independent buffers. Edited question