# VIM: How to add custom markers before lines

Tags: vim

I want to mark erroneous lines a source code. I detect the incorrect lines using an external program (e.g., [flake8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8)). When I save the source, I would like VIM to execute the external program and mark invalid lines.

I thought about different possibilities of "marking" the lines, like underlining full line or changing background colour. What I would like to do is to have an additional column on the left hand side of the text, where I could place some markers (e.g., ">") indicating the offending lines.

I know about the [flake8 vim plugin](https://github.com/nvie/vim-flake8), it displays full flask output and I want just small markers.

**Question:**

How can I add such a "special column"?

I thought about a separate window with width=1, but maybe there are better options.

(This question migrated from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832145/vim-disallow-focusing-a-window#comment24271311_16832145) after *innaM's* comment)

Comment: Yeah, the original question is a text book example of XY problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for your requirement, I suggest syntastic plugin, like others.

for your question, "add a customer marker before lines/special column" you should take a look `sign`.

```
:h sign
```

has more details, with examples.

Many plugins (syntastic, showmarkers....) have used this feature. you could add your own text, highlight and so on for your own sign.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the sources of the [Syntastic plugin](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic). Maybe you don't even have to write your own plugin, but can leverage Syntastic's powers.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [Syntastic](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2736)? It does everything you want and more.

The column you speak of is the "sign column", you can read all about it in `:h signs`.